# Find average GDP according to continent in SQL

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables- `Economics (land_code, gdp)` and `Continent (Land_code, Cont, Percentage)`. I need to create a query that calculates average GDP for Continent. In case the country is at the same time in several continents, we should also consider the percentage of GDP that belongs to continent. As I have understood `if Egypt has GDP of 100, then 90 belongs to Africa and 10 to Asia`, how can I implement this expression?

!!! ALREADY DONE)

Comment: The problem is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously,

```
select Economics.land_code, Economics.gdp * Continent.Percentage
  from ...
```

Comment: I've done the same, but something wrong with groupby continentname and counting averge

Comment: @nlimits Can you prepare example with data using sqlfiddle.com?